# why does my program sometimes never fully exit

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, x86-64, masm

I have created a simple assembly program, getting the DC for the screen then releasing the DC for the screen, every once in awhile (about 1/4 of the time, sometimes less sometimes more but average 1/4) the program doesn't end and when i try to break all the program it doesn't show what code is executing, I don't know why this is happening or how i can fix it

My code that i am running on visual studio, masm assembler.

```
includelib user32.lib
include externals.asm
.data
.code
start proc
    xor rcx, rcx
getdcfail:
    call GetDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je getdcfail
    mov r12, rax
releasedcfail:
    mov rdx, r12
    xor rcx, rcx
    call ReleaseDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je releasedcfail
    ret
start endp
end
```

here is externals.asm

```
extrn GetDC:proc
extrn ReleaseDC:proc
extrn GetDesktopWindow:proc
```

Comment: Probably not your issue, but is there a reason why you are jumping to `getdcfail:` when `ReleaseDC` fails?

Comment: that is a typo i tried many things, thats why getdesktopwindow is part of externals, ill see if that is my problem

Comment: fixing the typo did not fix the problem, first time i ran it without typo it didn't end

Comment: When you attach to your stuck process with a debugger, where is RIP?  Is it in an infinite loop or is it blocked on a system call?  If your debugger isn't showing you that, try a different debugger.  Or maybe just start the program outside a debugger and attach to it after it gets stuck?

Comment: You're not allocating any space for the 32 bytes of outgoing argument space that are always required regardless of the number of arguments you pass.  You also don't align the stack to the required 16-byte alignment.  The former problem could result in the functions you call destroying the return address stored on the stack when your function was called.

Comment: because you not call `ExitProcess`

Comment: and better declare imported winapi as `extrn __imp_GetDC:QWORD` and `call __imp_GetDC` for correct exit - you need `extern __imp_ExitProcess:QWORD` declare and `call __imp_ExitProcess`

Comment: what does the __imp_ do in front of the api calls

Comment: @NathanielSmith - it does optimization. because how import work - you do **indirect** call via variable `__imp_apiname`. this variable "implemented" by lib file (*kernel32.lib*, *User32.lib*, etc). when you do `call fn` for imported function - linker need create stub `fn: jmp __imp_fn` and you actually do call to this stub. better direct do `call __imp_fn`. but main - you **must** `call __imp_ExitProcess` and your 2 loop senseless. if you fail `ReleaseDC`- sequential calls of course fail too

Comment: of course and `sub rsp,028h(+10h*n)` (or like this) you need at begin for allocate 20h stack space and allign stack on 0x10